# user login fails even if correct details are provided

Tags: node.js

Working with http end points and trying to login user by searching database with his email.user password is hashed.when email provided is not in database it is returning 200 status code with no info.

I've tried self defined functions which checks if user obj is empty. even here the obj is not empty. Catch block is executing even if correct details are provided.

```
Router.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)

    res.send(user)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error)
  }
})

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
  const user = User.findOne({ email: email })

  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("Unable to login")
  }

  const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

  if (!isMatch) {
    throw new Error("Unable to login")
  }
  return user
}
```

Expected output is user. Actual output is empty with 400 status code.

Comment: You need to post the contents of `error` object inside the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem looks to be caused at the line:

```
const user = User.findOne({email : email})
```

and because you are not awaiting it or passing a callback it returns a Mongoose promise.

Then

```
const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
```

always evaluate to `false` since a you are comparing a function and a string.

```
!isMatch
```

evaluates to true which means you will always be throwing the `Error('Unable to login')`.

Comment: Thanks for responding dude . I just figured that out after I posted the prob. One more correction is throw isn't working instead I replaced it with return and it worked perfectly . If you have any idea about why throw didn't work lemme know.

Comment: When you say the throw wasn't working - do you mean it never entered the `if(!isMatch)` block?

Comment: Not even if(!user) it's executing the catch block with empty obj